# Can we make the default scrolling speed of the UIScrollView faster

Tags: trigger.io

Normally in iOS code we could do:

scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

Perhaps this should be something that can be set as a setting in the configuration json?

Comment: I'll actually be using this question as a basis for our first webinar on plugin development next Thursday (14th March 2013) - tune in!

Answer (score 0):

This would be doable as a native plugin if it was a priority for you; it's also the sort of thing we'll add to one of our core modules, but as we've not seen much demand for it, it's not something we can prioritise at the moment.